# Ways to combine two click functions, when one click function has a window size if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to combine two click functions to condense the code, but i'm not sure how. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//when clicking on a link hide the navigation links
$('nav a').click(function () {

    if ($(window).width() < 730) {
        $('nav').toggleClass('showNav');
        $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconTop');
        $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconMiddle');
        $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconBottom');
    }
});

//when clicking on icon hide and show the navigation links
//the icon is only visible when the screen size is less then 730px
$('.navToggle').click(function () {
    $('nav').toggleClass('showNav');
    $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconTop');
    $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconMiddle');
    $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconBottom');
});

});
```

Comment: This could be done using css media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
$('nav a, .navToggle').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('navToggle') || $(window).width() < 730) {
        $('nav').toggleClass('showNav');
        $('.navToggle').toggleClass('iconTop iconMiddle iconBottom');
    }
});
```

Basically, you check if the clicked element has the class `.navToggle`. If it doesn't, it check the window size before doing the action.